# How can I debug clj-apache-http?

Tags: clojure, oauth, leiningen

I'm trying to get an OAuth application up, but I fail because the API servers won't talk to me. Unfortunatly the used [clj-apache-http](https://github.com/rnewman/clj-apache-http) won't tell me what was the problem, I only get this warning:

```
WARNUNG: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2FSERVERNAME"}
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: JSON error (unexpected character): I (example.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: JSON error (unexpected character): I (example.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
        at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__4511.invoke(core.clj:4905)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4904)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:409)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
```

Ok, now that isn't helping me. There is a strange character **I** as the first one in the response - that's clearly no JSON.

I want to get the log level of apaches HTTPClient up to DEBUG now, but I don't know how to set system properties via **leiningen**. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to get all requests by **clj-apache-http** through a local debugging proxy:

```
(require ['com.twinql.clojure.http :as 'http])

(:content 
  (http/get (java.net.URI. "http://yourhost.com")
    :parameters (http/map->params {
      :default-proxy (http/http-host
        :host "127.0.0.1" 
        :port 8765)}) :as :string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could add this to your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=DEBUG
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Which will dump all communication to your log file. This is useful don't want to change the code that makes the request.